# RXJS5 chaining like Promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

Hy all,
whats the best way to chaining RXJS5 results, like promises?

```
interface MyObj{
  name : string
  url: string
  html: any // async
}

// promise chaining, pretty simple
getMyObjWithPromise()
  .then(myObj=>{

   // promise, we get back html from myObj.url async
   return getMyObjHtmlWithPromise(myObj)
  })
  .then(myObj=>{

   // done, here we have myObj with html
  })
```

Similar with RXJS5? 
We need share myObj across the streams, and modify obj props asynchronously...

Answer (score 3):

With Promises and chaining `then()` calls you're able to modify the result passed the to the consecutive handlers.

Most similar option in RxJS is [`map()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) operator or [`concatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) if you want to return another Observable. In some situations also [`do`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) could be useful but it can't modify the value passed through.

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getMyObjWithPromise())
  .map(myObj => {
    return myObj;
  })
  .concatMap(myObj => {
    // promise, we get back html from myObj.url async
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getMyObjHtmlWithPromise(myObj));
  })
  .subscribe(myObj => {
    // done, here we have myObj with html
  });
```

Note that usually you need to have at least one subscriber in order to make the Observable emit values.